# How to ignore integer start with 0

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a web application. I have two text boxes, one is `txtEmployeeID`, and one is `txtEmployeeName`. What I am trying to do here is when the user enter `EmployeeID` in the `txtEmployeeID`, the name of the employee will show up in the `txtEmployeeName`. I got this part working so far. However, if the `employeeID` start with bunch of `0`, let say `00000345`, the user need to enter all `00000345` in the `employeeID` in order to show that `employeeName`. I am wondering if there a way for user to just enter `345` and then that `00000345`'s `employeeName` will display in the `txtEmployeeName`? Help will be appreaciated.

For Example

```
EmployeeID   EmployeeName
00000345     James Murray
```

In my text box.

```
Employee ID: 345
```

It will display

```
Employee Name: James Murray
```

My DB Query

```
@Employee_ID    varchar(8) = NULL

SELECT s.Employee_ID, p.FIRST_NAME, p.LAST_NAME
    FROM [dbo].[Employee] e INNER JOIN [dbo].[Person] p ON e.PERSON_ID = p.PERSON_ID
    WHERE p.Employee_ID = @Employee_ID
```

Comment: Eh, *convert* to `int` or `long`? or `TrimStart('0')`? to *add zeroes* - use padding: `.PadLeft(8, '0');`

Comment: How are you looking up the employee? If your database uses strings as IDs, then "00035" and "35" are different... you should either use numbers as your IDs, or format the number that the user has entered to the expect length.

Comment: Show us the code that does the filtering.

Comment: @JonSkeet, It is from my db, I've got it all set up

Comment: You may have it "all set up" but you haven't told us *anything* about it...

Comment: @Jon, I have edited my question, please see the update

Comment: Right - so as I suspected, your primary key is a string, not a number. You can either change that to make it a number, or you can format the number that the user typed in. Which do you want?

Comment: @JonSkeet, thanks for your help, odlan's answer work :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

```
int num = Convert.ToInt32(txtEmployeeID.Text);
string idNum = num.ToString("00000000");
txtEmployeeID.Text = idNum.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Int32.ToString("000") to format an integer in this manner.  For details, see [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) and [Int32.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wch342y):

`txtEmployeeID.text.ToString("00000000") == EmployeeID;`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
string EmplId = txtEmployeeID.Text;
EmplId = EmplId.TrimStart(new Char[] { '0' } )
```

Answer (score 0):

I answer your query assuming that the length of the EmployeeID is fixed (as per your question it is 8)

Let the user to type employeeID in the textfield with no zeroes

Use the following C# code to add leading zeroes to your parameter before sending it to the database query.

string EmployeeID = String.Format("{0:00000000}", int.Parse(txtEmployeeID.ToString())).ToString();